# Button in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

i've created a Datagrid Control in WPF in which there is a button in the cell of each row of

Column(Subgraph). how can i make the Button visible only for some cell-rows in the Subgraph-Column.

```
 XAML:
 <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="subgraphtyp" Header="H" Width="50">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Button Name="btnTable" Visibility="Visible" Height="20" Width="25"   
                       Click="Button_Table_Click">
                  <Image Height="16" Source="Subgraph.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="16"/>
               </Button>
           </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be to bind the visibility of the button to some value in the grid that would determine if it should be visible for that row.  Basically, create a function in the back end code that retrieves the data for that row, parses it, and then returns "Visible" if the button should be shown, or "Hidden" if it should not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

XAML Attribute Usage

```
dataGridColumn Visibility="Visible"/>
dataGridColumn Visibility="Collapsed"/>


private void cbHideColumn_Changed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
     if (this.dataGrid1 != null)
       {
         if (cb.IsChecked == true)
            this.dataGrid1.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         else if (cb.IsChecked == false)
            this.dataGrid1.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       }
   }
```